# C/C++, Visual Studio, Юникод/Многобайтовые кодировки

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

В настройках проекта **Visual Studio** можно выбирать набор используемых символов. Обычно там есть два пункта:

```
Многобайтовая кодировка;
Юникод.
```

В чем разница?

Я раньше считал, что многобайтовая кодировка - это **ANSI**, 8 битные символы, зависимость от кодовой страницы. А юникод - это **UTF16-LE**, который обычно упаковывается в **wchar_t**, и при этом значащий символ может быть представлен 1 или 2 символами **wchar_t**.

Считал я так потому, что при выборе многобайтовой кодировки - **WinAPI** макросы разворачивались из, например, **CreateFile()** в **CreateFileA()**, а синоним **TCHAR** скрывал за собой **char**. То есть, многобайтовая кодировка в настройках проекта приводила к использованию **ANSI** версий **WinAPI** функций и типов.

Но теперь я окончательно запутался. Помогите разобраться в этом вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Самое первое, что нужно понять, что юникод и utf-XXX - это разные штуки. Самая ближайшая аналогия - классы и объекты.

Юникод - это просто таблица, в которой каждому символу сопоставлен какой то код-число.

utf-8, utf-16-le и другие - это то, как этот код-число кодируется в "железе".

То есть, самому юникоду побоку на байты, на биты. Там числа.

utf-8 сделан так, что если использовать только первые 128 символов юникода, то по внешнему виду его нельзя отличить от кодировки ANSI. Они совпадают с точностью до битового представления (если конечно не считать [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), который может быть вначале). Эта особенность как раз и дала возможность легко добавить поддержку юникода (юникода, а не utf16).

Но у uft-8 есть один фатальный недостаток - многие функции с ним "тяжело работают". К примеру, посчитать длину строки (strlen). И тут начинаются танцы с бубном, что считать длину строки - количество байт или количество символов или количество видимых пользователю символов (ага, не все символы юникода видимы. часть из них это "модификаторы". Например, добавляем спец модификатор к `И` и получам `Й`. Длина строки будет 4 2 или 1, в зависимости от того, как считать).

В UTF16 с этим чуточку проще. Там почти всегда все символы по два байта. Длину считать легко, ну кроме тех случаев, когда кодируется двумя двухбайтовыми.

И Майкрософт решила использовать UTF16-LE. Это интересное решение, легко кодится и большинстве случаев пользователи-программисты просто поменяли свои типы на t* типы и все заработало. Но сделали глупость и назвали это "юникодом".

Comment: Двухбайтовые символы были вполне себе нормальным юникодом. А потом набежали всякие филологи / египтологи и начали соревноваться "хто засабмитит больше безнадежно мертвых символов или наклепает новых".

Comment: правильнее говорить так "двухбайтовые кодировки хорошо кодировали юникод" , а потом "набежала молодёж и Эппл и натулили сотни эмоджи на каждый чих (а по факту это и есть египтологи)"

Comment: Я понимаю, что такое юникод. Это просто таблица, где определенным символам соответствует код (точка). А **UTF-16LE** - это формат представления строки с юникод символами, в котором каждая точка в таблице юникода представлена одним или двумя двухбайтовыми символами (в **Windows** это тип **wchar_t**) с порядком **LE**.

Comment: В **Windows** (в большинстве версий, например в **WindowsNT**) в ядре и в файловой системе используется юникод, представленный в виде **UTF-16LE**. Не все символы кодируются одним двухбайтовым символов, и надеяться на это совсем не стоит.

Comment: Я тогда вообще не понимаю, что такое *многобайтовая кодировка* в представлении **Microsoft**, и почему этот режим в проекте приводит к вызову **ANSI** версий функций **WinAPI**

Comment: Господа, вы неверно понимаете, что такое **UTF-16**. Это формат представления юникода. Такой же полноценный, как **UTF-8** или **UTF-32**. Если **UTF-16** двухбайтовый, это не значит, что можно закодировать лишь до 65 535 символов, это значит, что символы юникода кодируются либо одним двухбайтовым символом, либо двумя, если код слишком велик и необходимо использовать *суррогатные* пары. Это компромисс между расходом памяти (как в **UTF-32**) и удобством. Например, при использовании **UTF-8** строки на некоторых языках, например, азиатских, будут занимать больше места, чем строки в **UTF-16**

Comment: такое ощущение, что в комментариях два разных Максима.

Comment: Я просто веду несколько дискуссий в разных местах и из-за этого иногда теряюсь...